# Increasing INode Limit

Tags: linux, centos

Is there a way to increase the INode Limit in CentOS without adding partition ? I got some 5 million files to be stored but it may increase in future.

Comment: Your question is better suited for serverfault. It is [answered partially here](http://serverfault.com/questions/111857/linux-help-im-running-out-of-inodes). Please move your question to serverfault. Thank you

Comment: It depends on what file system you are using - some (e.g. `ufs`, `ext2`) have static inode tables that can't be grown without re-creating the file system, while others (e.g. `xfs`, `vxfs`) dynamically allocate inodes on demand (sometimes with the ability to put limits on dynamic allocation).

Answer (score 0):

The inode limit on a filesystem is fixed when creating it, i.e., at `mkfs(8)` time, e.g. for `mk2fs(8)` with the flag `-i <bytes-per-inode>`. Many have a configuration file giving "standard" sets of flags, e.g. `mke2fs.conf(5)`. Depending on what you are doing, probably something like the suggested Usenet news configuration (i.e., `inode_ratio = 4096`) is what you need.